# Static .a library not building gives the Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I know there is lots of question but i have asked because i am not able to find the answer.

I have my xxx.a  static library. I have added in my project but when i run it throws the error

```
 Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_Reachability", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in CheckConnection.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_MobileSDK", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in Utility.o
```

I have user lipo -info (mylibraypath) commend

it returns My library are: armv7 arm64

My valid architecture : armv7 arm64

Architecture are : $(ARCHS_STANDARD)

I am not able to run the app in simulator please help

Comment: You need to build the static library with support for x86_64 to run in the simulator.

Comment: can you give me the link how to build?

Answer (score 1):

You need to build it also for the simulator. So choose your library and simulator and build. Find the product (the .a file) and check it with `lipo` you should see it's `x86_64`. Then find your other .a file built for `armv7` and `arm64` and make one fat library by

```
lipo -create lib1.a lib2.a -output libcombined.a
```

where `lib1.a` is the `x86_64` lib and `lib2.a` is `armv7` `arm64` lib.

Comment: Ok so i need to use diff .a file while running on the simulator that build with simulator and diff for the device.

Comment: Don't you mean `x86_64`?

Comment: Absolutely true, 7 years later :)